# form_for Model.new "f.error_messages"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

the `f.error_messages` form builder helper has been depreciated in Rails 3.

How do I get the error messages for a form with the opening tag:

```
<%= form_for Model.new %>
```

(I'm using Model.new because I want to be able to load an undefined multiple number of these forms onto a single page)

Comment: If you call something like `@model = Model.new()` in your controller, you can use that for as many forms as you want (given that they are the same `model`).

Comment: I'm a big fan of `simple_form` which does have a `error_notification` method.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.** Not with a form builder like this one.

Basically, error messages are stored **inside** the object you use to build a form. If you build a new one every time, you get a clean object without errors.

What you need to do is persist the object filled in by the user between requests. Typically this is done by creating a new object in controller:

```
@model = Model.new
```

The essence of this is, that `new` view uses `@model` to render a form. And the trick is to have a possibility to render the same view in other actions that also provide `@model`. That said, if you do something like this in `create`:

```
@model = Model.new(model_params)
if @model.save
  # success
else
  render :new
end
```

It can render `new` view, because it assigns `@model` too; in this case, it will contain errors with messages and other stuff. All this is inside `@model.errors` – which is always empty in `new` action.

It's not that different for multiple forms, bear in mind that you always submit only one. You may switch to rendering an array of forms, in that case you could have `@models` array:

```
@models = [form1, form2, form3]
```

In that case, if saving fails, assign that array again and either replace the form the user tried to fill in (if you can identify it), ot prepend/append that form with errors to that array.

```
@models[index_of_submitted_form] = form_from_user #replace
@models << form_from_user # append
@models.unshift form_from_user # prepend
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, you can access errors using `@model.errors`

```
<%= form_for @model = Model.new do |f| %>
  <% @model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p><%= msg %></p>
  <% end %>

  # ...
  # ...
  # ...
<% end %>
```